# The File Could Not Be Found Symfony Upload

Tags: php, symfony

I have two fields in my entity that serve as the filename of a file: a contract and a license. I programmed the contract upload on page A, then duplicated it and changed it for the license on page B. Page A with the contract upload works, Page B with the exact same process I get a generic error "The file could not be found." and nothing in the logs as to why.

From the Entity (contract works, license doesn't):

```
/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="contract", type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize="600000",
 *     maxSizeMessage="The file is too large. Allowed maximum size is 8MB",
 *     mimeTypes={"image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/jpeg", "application/pdf"}
 * )
 */
private $contract;

/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="license", type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize="600000",
 *     maxSizeMessage="The file is too large. Allowed maximum size is 8MB",
 *     mimeTypes={"image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/jpeg", "application/pdf"}
 * )
 */
private $license;
```

From the controller (contractAction uploads, uploadLicenseAction on submit shows the error listed above, does not make it inside the `$form->isValid()` condition):

```
/**
 * @Route("/contract", name="contract")
 * @Template()
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function contractAction(Request $request) {
    $em         = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user       = $this->getUser();
    $store = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ShadowBundle:Store')->find($user->getId());

    // If already signed, redirect to upload license page
    if (!empty($store->getContract())) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('store_license_upload');
    }

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($store)
        ->add('contract', FileType::class, [
            'required'   => true,
            'data_class' => null
        ])
        ->add('upload_contract', SubmitType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']
        ])
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $file_dir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . "/../web/images/uploads/store/contract";

        /**
         * @var UploadedFile $contract
         */
        $contract = $store->getContract();
        $filename = uniqid() . $contract->getClientOriginalName();

        $contract->move($file_dir, $filename);
        $store->setContract($filename);

        $em->persist($store);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('store_awaiting_approval');
    }

    return [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ];
}

/**
 * @Route("/license_upload", name="store_license_upload")
 * @Template()
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function uploadLicenseAction(Request $request) {
    $em         = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user       = $this->getUser();
    $store= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ShadowBundle:Store')->find($user->getId());

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($store)
        ->add('license', FileType::class, [
            'data_class' => null,
            'required'   => false
        ])->add('upload_license', SubmitType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']
        ])->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()){
        exit(dump('test'));
    }

    return [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ];
}
```

The view for this is just simple html outputting the form in it's entirety with `{{ form(form) }}`

This seems to have something to do with the `@Assert` because if I remove it, it works fine. If I remove the `@Assert\File` on the working contract and try to submit the license again, it works so it has something to do with two asserts in the same entity, but I have another entity that also has two `@Assert\File` and that one works without a problem.

Thoughts? I know I could assert in the form declaration, but I would really rather not break away from the way I've been doing it for consistency.

EDIT: Even removing the assert from the Entity and adding it to the form's constraints still didn't work and I got the same exact error.